# How to use a glossary with xindy that is not displayed

Tags: glossaries, xindy

According to several posts in the web the following error is related to not displaying the glossary:

```
Error in line 426:


; additional letter groups

(define-letter-group "glsnumbers"
   :prefixes ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")
   :before "A")
ERROR: "A" does not name a letter group in
(DEFINE-LETTER-GROUP "glsnumbers" :PREFIXES
 ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9") :BEFORE "A")

***Call to xindy failed***

Possible cause of problem:

No language detected.
Have you remembered to use \printglossary
or \printglossaries in your document?

Check 'diss_org.anx' for details
```

This in fact works without error if I print all of my three glossaries.

How to get rid of that?

I  use glossaries, xindy and the following options

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc=true,shortcuts,xindy,section,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
```

P.S.: Sorry I do not have time to setup an MWE since I have to submit my thesis tomorrow. I can make one later

---

### Update

The problem disappeared with updating TeXLive.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, without MWE it is hard to say what happened, but I think you should check if you have set the document language with babel (or polyglosia in the case of xelatex).

This example works for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc=true,shortcuts,xindy,section,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{gls:cha}{name=chobot,description=Lorem}
\newglossaryentry{gls:czi}{name=čížek,description=ipsum}
\newglossaryentry{gls:dat}{name=datel,description=sin}
\newglossaryentry{gls:ili}{name=ikar,description=dolor}
Tenhle \gls{gls:dat} se směje jak \gls{gls:cha}, \gls{gls:czi} zas jako \gls{gls:ili}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Compile sequence:

```
latex file
makeglossaries file
latex file
```

You shouldn't run `xindy` directly, but use the `makeglossaries` instead

[image: sample result]

Comment: I did. In contrast to you example I use 2 userdefined glossaries. One of them I do not display.

Comment: I set the two document languages by `\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}
    \setotherlanguage{german}`